# Set $scope var in directive in ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this element:

```
<img data-address ng-click="dishInfo = dish">
```

And directive:

```
app.directive('address', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function() {
                        console.log($scope.dishInfo);
                        $(".modal").modal();  
                })
            }
        }
    }
])
```

When i click on image in my console i got `Resource`:
 `Resource { id=1, dishes={...}, category=[1],...}`
in my `.modal`  this code:

```
<div class="partner fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content">
             {{ dishInfo.id }}
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

But when modal window(after click on image) has been opened - i see empty block, no id. why?

Comment: They probably don't have the same scope. Could you please post a demo so I could get more information?

Comment: @AR7 , they are in the same module. that they may still be different?

Comment: It depends on whether or not they are using the same controller.

Comment: Yes, it's in same controller

Comment: If you write just `dishInfo` does anything appear? How about if you write `dishInfo | json`?

Comment: how do you mean? I do not understand, how do I get json and where it lead?)

Comment: `json` is just a filter. You've provided so little information I was wondering if the object even exists in the eye of the scope. Maybe `dishInfo` exists but not `dishInfo.id`. Anyways I'm taking shots in the dark because you aren't providing more code or a demo.

Comment: Example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/FkZHXkP2JRV2bED1vPoB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out

## Not best practice

(if you want to keep doing it the same way)

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VCewVczN4t54PQ6bf1Rh?p=preview
Change

```
ng-click="dishInfo = dish"
```

to

```
ng-click="$parent.dishInfo = dish"
```

Turns out you have to explicitly refer to the scope in the form of the $parent object because ng-click creates it's own scope.

## Best practice

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8VOFkOP1r1RfILZ7gKfc?p=preview

Change

```
ng-click="dishInfo = dish"
```

to

```
ng-click="setDish(dish)"
```

And have a method in your js file called setDish that does something like

```
$scope.setDish = function(dish) {
    $scope.dishInfo = dish;
}
```

Comment: In second example modal is empty

Comment: oops! I overwrote it by accident. Give me one second.

Answer (score -1):

You should use your scope object in your directive to achieve this:

```
app.directive('address', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope : {
                dishinfo: "="
            }
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function() {
                        console.log($scope.dishInfo);
                        $(".modal").modal();  
                })
            }
        }
    }
])
```

In your partial:

```
<img data-address dishinfo="dish">
```

And you declare the value of dish in your controller that wraps this partial.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not necessarily as that makes it have an isolate scope and now is disconnected completely from the scope of the controller. Also I don't see how this will solve the problem. It sounds more like a recommendation than a solution.

Comment: Where is your modal HTML located. If it is inside the directive template then it will have access to the $scope. I guess I'd need more information on your entire set up (i.e. modal location, where the value of dish is declared) to be more help.  Sorry for non-answer answer