# Pass CSS value from a ng-repeater to an outside element.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I pass values from my **ng-repeater** to an **outside** element?

Lets say, I have this simple ng-repeater, with an ng-click function, which will return different values depending on the index value.

```
<data ng-repeat="x in array">
  <a href ng-click="move_arrow={left: arrowvalue($index)}">
     {{ x }} 
  </a>
</data>
```

the *arrowvalue* could for example be someting like this.

```
  $scope.arrowvalue = function(value){
        if (value == 0){ return '10%' }
        else if (value == 1){ return '20%' }
        else {return '100%' }
    }
```

so if I want to use '*move_arrow*' outside the scope (the ng-repeat), how do I pass that value to a ng-style.

```
<span ng-style="move_arrow"></span>
```

I noticed if the span with the 'move_arrow' is inside the repeater the value is passed, but when its outside it isn't

Comment: a little confused. why can't you put move_arrow in controller's $scope as well?

Comment: hi ABOS, sorry English is not my native language :) But someone already helped me with the problem, thank you anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because move_arrow is inside ng-repeat its scope will be available only inside that. If you wnat to use that outside ng-repeat then you can create another $scope variable like this :

```
$scope.arrowvalue = function(value){
        if (value == 0){ 
            $scope.outerStyle={left:'10%'};
            return '10%' }
        else if (value == 1){
            $scope.outerStyle={left:'20%'};
            return '20%' }
        else {
              $scope.outerStyle={left:'100%'};
            return '100%' }
    }
```

And use $scope.outerStyle varible in span

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a question very similar to this before. The answer is here:

[Set $scope var in directive in ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043162/set-scope-var-in-directive-in-ng-click/29043949#29043949)

Basically you're right in saying that both ng-click and ng-repeat do some weird stuff with creating their own scopes. You could use the $parent scope, but the best way you can combat this is to create a function inside your controller and call that function instead of doing it inline.

So your ng-click would look something like:

```
<a href ng-click="setStyle(arrowvalue($index))">
```

and in your controller you would have something like:

```
$scope.setStyle = function(value) {
    $scope.move_arrow = {'left': value};
};
```

Comment: I followed Anita's example, its similar to yours, but you have provided some wonderful information too, thanks a lot! Still learning a lot! :)

Comment: No problem. As a side note I'm pretty sure you have to put the css property `left` in double or single quotes inside the `ng-style`. At least that's the way I've always seen it written.

Comment: Just both, as a string and as an 'object', both are working! But thanks for the side-note! :)